# SQL Server 2012 Relating table row value to column name in results table

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

First time posting here...Please forgive formatting issues. After days of trying to find a similar situation upon which to derive a solution to my problem, I still find myself inside a Rubik's cube. I'm trying to create a "report" that will show student performance on exams and their demographics. Here's the scenario:

I have an exam source table with the following columns:

**Table Name: FOT2012PRE**

> ItemID    int (Primary Key)
>   ItemNum   nchar(10)   (Corresponding column name in results table)
>   ItemStem nvarchar(1000)   (This is the question stem.)
>   IC1   nvarchar(1000)  (This is the first answer choice.)
>   IC2   nvarchar(1000)  (This is the second answer choice.)
>   IC3   nvarchar(1000)  (This is the third answer choice.)
>   IC4   nvarchar(1000)  (This is the fourth answer choice.)
>   PriAns    nvarchar(10)    (This is the Correct answer choice- N/A for
>   demographic items.)

There are additional columns to identify graphics, videos, course, unit, demog flag.

Here's some of the data in the exam source table:

> ItemID    ItemNum ItemStem    IC1 IC2 IC3 IC4 PriAns
>  1    Item1       What
>   is your current grade level?  9th Grade   10th Grade  11th Grade  12th
>   Grade NULL
>  2  Item2       What is your gender?
>     Male    Female  NULL    NULL    NULL

As students answer each question, their selection is recorded in a results table specific for that exam. This results table has the following columns:

**Table Name: FOT2012PRERESULTS**

> ResultsID int          (Primary Key)
>   StudentID nvarchar(255)   (Unique ID for each student taking exam)
>   LastItem  nvarchar(255)   (Updated with each answer processed - for exam
>   re-entry)
>  Item1           nvarchar(255)   (Answer recorded for Item1:
>   "C" if correct; Choice if incorrect)
>  Item2
>   nvarchar(255) (Answer recorded for Item2: same as for all other
>   questions in the exam)

Here some sample data from the results table:

> ResultsID StudentID   LastItem    Item1   Item2  Item3
>   743  MD911059935  67          IC2 IC2    C
>   744  IC2  IC2    C
>   746  MD911059949  67          IC2 IC2    IC4
>   934  MD3590986869 46          IC2 IC1    IC3

Ultimately I want to be able to have my report to look something like this:

**Item: What is your current grade level?**

> 9th Grade       (number of IC1 responses)
>  10th Grade      (number
>   of IC2 responses)
>  11th Grade      (number of IC3 responses)
>   12th Grade      (number of IC4 responses)
>  No Response     (number
>   of NULL responses)

These results would take the form of a table and also compare results on a local, district, state, and national basis, but I can do the corresponding nested query to handle that. For this solution, I am open to and believe that it's probably best implemented as a stored procedure since there are about 40 exams spread across a lot of states and thousands of students. I can pass table names and other values as needed. Access to the report is individualized based on which exam was administered for a particular class.

I appreciate any assistance and suggestions. I must respectfully ask for your indulgence in providing specifics as to any joins or pivots. I am a dinosaur and program in ASP JavaScript. My attempts down that path thus far have only put me inside this cube...and I need some light to find my way out. If I've omitted anything, please let me know.

Thank you...

Update:

Here is part of the SP I've created to get the data normalized into one table:

```
Create Table #rawtemp 
( 
Choice nchar(5),
ChoiceCount float
)

Create Table #temp 
( 
Item nchar(5),
Choice nchar(5),
ChoiceCount float
)
-- Query the results table and tally by response
```

while (@i <= 8) 
    begin
    SET @examcolinc = cast(@i as varchar(2)) -- increment based on loop
    SET @examcol = @res2+@examcolinc -- append increment to create incremental column name - base value is the word 'item'

```
Declare @xsql nvarchar(1000) --this query cycles through each unique column in the results table, counting and grouping according to each response
Set @xsql = 'Select '+@examcol+' AS Choice, Count(*) AS ChoiceCount FROM dbo.'+@pretest+' WHERE '+@examcol+' <> '''' AND StudentID LIKE '''+@st+''' Group By '+@examcol
```

--  Exec (@xsql)
    --Store the raw tally into a temp table
    Insert #rawtemp Exec (@xsql)
    Insert #temp --illustrates the incrementing column name (e.g., Item1, Item 2, etc.)
    (
    Item
    )
    Values
    (
    @examcol
    )

```
SET @i = @i+1 --increment the loop by one
end <br>
```

Here is the results from the query:
Choice  ChoiceCount
IC1     323
IC2     154
IC3     34
IC4     20
IC1     275
IC2     244
IC1     423
IC2     62
IC3     10
IC4     7
...

Here is the result from the #temp insertion:
Item    Choice  ChoiceCount
Item1   NULL    NULL
Item2   NULL    NULL
Item3   NULL    NULL
Item4   NULL    NULL
Item5   NULL    NULL
Item6   NULL    NULL
Item7   NULL    NULL
Item8   NULL    NULL

Just trying to get them married up...Since it is the "name" of the column that I need to insert as a value in the temp table, I've been beating my brains out trying to figure it out. Any help would be most appreciated. It may be that the above temp table feeds into another temp table, which ultimate will be joined with the exam source table so that I can retrieve the question stem, the distractors, the unit number, and the associated benchmark/standard.

Comment: The results table is hard to work with.  The value of a given record's "Item3" field might mean something totally different to another record, because it might be a different exam altogether.  I think you need to keep the results table with "resultsId" which describes the exam taken, "studentId" the student who took it, and their lastItem, and split the remaining data into (for example) "answers" table which contains resultsId, questionId and answerValue.  This will eliminate the crosstab nature of the report you are trying to create and let you use much more efficient joins to build it.

Comment: That was my initial schema intent, however, client requirements ultimately required that each exam have its own results table, precisely because each exam item is different depending on the exam. Each item is tied to a specific unit and benchmark and each student taking item 3 gets the same question. When updated, a new exam version is created (source and results)...important always to compare apples to apples for these exams. I appreciate the suggestion, but just have to have a solution based on what I have...

Comment: Ugh...I'm so sorry to hear that, and IMO that is crazy.  It removes the ease-of-use and performance of a relational database and leaves you with countless excel spreadsheets.  If possible fight to get that changed and offer another reporting option that delivers these single-exam tables.  Yes the client is always right except when it comes to architecture, which is why they hired you.

Comment: Build a temporary table and populate it with normalized data before running a report.  That will at least allow you to use a single join to get a count of how many students chose answerX for questionY.  It's probably more efficient than building a three-million character query for each report you want to run.

Comment: @James - Thanks for the recommendation and I have been diligently trying to work my way through it and learning the nuances of T-SQL at the same time. I've built the temp table procedure, but cannot find a way to add the dynamic column name as a value in the temp table. The whole purpose of the temp table is to show:

Comment: To continue: The whole purpose of the temp table is to show Item'n', Choice, and ChoiceCount. Since Item 'n' is dynamic using the loop (Item1, Item2, etc), how can I include it in the temp table? In JavaScript, I could use the .name versus .value property to store the column name and include it in an insert statement. But this is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your temp table like this:

```
ExamId (exam source table name, eg 'FOT2012PRE') 
ItemNum (from exam source table, eg 'Item1') 
StudentId (eg 'MD911059935') 
Response (eg 'IC1', or NULL)
```

- In the event of multiple schools using the exact same "examId", add columns to distinguish between the schools

That will give you one row per unique exam/question number/student who answered, and his response if any.

To populate this table, loop through the exam source table(s); each row's ItemNum field contains one of the column names in the result table.  Retrieve studentId + the value of the corresponding result column (eg Item2, containing "IC4") from the results table, and store them in the temp table.

In the built query that you are currently using, can you not:

```
Set @xsql = 'Select ''' + @examcol + ''' as Item, '+@examcol+' AS Choice, Count(*) AS ChoiceCount FROM dbo.'+@pretest+' WHERE '+@examcol+' <> '''' AND StudentID LIKE '''+@st+''' Group By '+@examcol
```

Comment: The exam source table and the results tables are different, and I've tried creating a table using a parameter/variable for a column name...It didn't like it. I've updated the question to show you what I currently have. Any help would be great!!

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, but it gave me an error that the column "Item" was not part of an aggregate function. What you've done is use the incrementing column name as a text element with an alias of "Item." I cannot thank you enough...and my keyboard thanks you since I'll now type a little more softly and quit banging my head on it. You've removed the bottleneck in my project!!!